# APA Citation for a undergrad-level book review

Tags: technique, editing, formatting, citations, apa

I'm writing a book review for sociology on the book *Sidewalk* by Mitchell Duneier.

This book is the ONLY source for my whole paper. It is the only citation that I am using and the only outside source that is discussed.

In this case, is it necessary to put an in-text citation with his name every time? Or, could I just put the page numbers in the citation, without the name, since it is only that single source? I'm quoting very short phrases--always less than a sentence.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge this is not possible.  In googling this real quick, everything I found also backed up that notion.  [Purdue OWL](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/560/02/) is one of my favorite go-to places for citation questions and they also make no mentioning of being able to do this shortcut.  Everything I have read says that you need to have the quote fully cited each time.

My advice would be to write each quote out as if they are all unique sources.  Then I would email your professor or talk to them next class.

If nothing else, you can always ask the professor in class next time about how you want to know if there is any shortcuts for in-text citation when dealing with a singular source for a whole paper or if you have multiple quotes from the same source that follow each other in the same paragraph.

I don't think you are entirely wrong in your notion.  I remember being able to do something similar, but I can't recall if it was MLA or APA, though this may have changed since I last had to write an essay.  From my research, I would go with the answer of no it is not possible.